# Crontab output storage

Tags: ubuntu, logging, cron

I am having trouble logging the output and/or errors of my crontab processes.  I think the code I have may even be preventing the process to be run entirely, but it is hard to check what is causing the error.

```
0 12 * 9-12 0 python /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/Folder/process.py > /home/log/log.log 2>>&1
```

I am attempting to run file process.py every Sunday at 12:00 PM and store the output in log.log.  I have run processes on crontab without issues in the past.

Comment: Try with the full path of python. For example /usr/bin/python. If you still don't see output in log.log, check your mail. When cron fails, it usually sends a mail to the user id that set up the cron

Comment: You have a single '>' for STDOUT and double '>>' for STDERR. Make sure that is what is intended and not a typo.